# jQuery datepicker not working in jQuery Dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, dialog, jquery-ui-datepicker

jQuery datepicker works fine on a static page, but I can't get it to work on a jQuery Dialog page. This is a wordpress site.

I know everything necessary is included because it works on a static page. The dialog page is triggered with a button click.

This is the code on the static page (working):

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" name="datepicker" value="" />
```

Here is the input box on the dialog page, which is created dynamically (nothing happens when clicking in the input box):

```
<input type="text" value="" data_original_for_sale_date="" id="for_sale_date" class="datepicker">
```

Here is the jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'mm/dd/yy'
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. (I'm a newbie...)

Comment: Can you also show us the code, which you use to create the dialog?

Comment: When you open the dialog in its callback add the datepicker code. This is happening because when you run the code first time the dialogs datepicker is not yet visible to jquery. So say if you have a button where you call opendialog() or something after that run the datepicker() function again not the ready() fun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your jquery code by this

```
    $(document).ready(function($) {
      $('body').on('focus',".datepicker", function(){
        $(this).datepicker({
          dateFormat : 'mm/dd/yy'
        });
      });
    });
```